# Load data from MongoDB into R

Tags: r, mongodb, find

I am trying to query my `MongoDB` database from `R`.
I think I lost part of it in the process.
Does `R` have any limit, and how can I ensure all my records are loaded into `R`?

**Code:**

```
# inspect number of record in mongodb
db.complaints.count()
>395 853

# write a query to load data into R
library(dplyr)
complaints = data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
db = "customers.complaints"
cursor = mongo.find(mongo, db)

i = 1
while (mongo.cursor.next(cursor))
{
    tmp = mongo.bson.to.list(mongo.cursor.value(cursor))
    tmp.df = as.data.frame(t(unlist(tmp)), stringsAsFactors=F)
    complaints = rbind.fill(complaints, tmp.df)
}
```

I get `[1] 47077    15` after checking the loading in `R` with `dim(complaints)`.

How can make sure I get all my collections in `R`?

Comment: I assume you're using `rmongodb` and not `RMongo`, correct? Is `customer.complaints` the same as `complaints`? What do you get when you run `mongo.find(mongo, db)`? What do you get when you run `mongo.count(mongo, db)`?

Comment: I have the followingIn MongoDB

Comment: I have the following in MongoDB  database  : customers , collection : complaints. I am using rmongodb package in R and I have 395853 when I run mongo.count(mongo,db)

Answer (score -1):

http://www.analyticbridge.com/profiles/blogs/time-issue-in-creating-a-huge-data-frame-from-mongodb-collection

the above code using environment variables might help you! Please do comment over here if you get a solution.